# Antd tree select customization to have child with same name without confusing user

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dropdown, antd

As shown in image for two different parents, child title to be shown is same in tree select dropdown. In such scenario is there any possibility to show all children related to one parent at one place or in one color without changing title name.
From my understanding, I don't find any solution for this. Any help is highly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: I make a sandbox with some solution its maybe helps you; https://codesandbox.io/s/checkable-antd-4-18-2-forked-43que?file=/index.js

Answer (score 0):

Key and text values on tree items are different from each other. That's why you can create a method to edit the keys when passing the tree items to the antd component.
E.g:

```
    function getTreeItmes(items,parent) {
       return items?.map(i => {
         return {
              ...i,
              key:parent?.key + '.' + i.key,
              items:getTreeItems(i.children,i)
             }
    });
 }
```